# Plotting the 1D Power Spectrum of an Image

Tags: python, image-processing, signal-processing, fft

I want to plot the power spectrum of natural images so I've been using code from this resource: https://bertvandenbroucke.netlify.app/2019/05/24/computing-a-power-spectrum-in-python/ but I just want to verify that this is the correct implementation. Here's my specific code:

```
def power_spectrum(im_path,plot=True,transform=True):
    if type(im_path) == str:
        image = PIL.Image.open(im_path)
        if transform:
            image = torchvision.transforms.functional.center_crop(image,(256,256))
            image = np.array(torchvision.transforms.functional.rgb_to_grayscale(image))
        # print(image.shape)
        else:
            image = np.array(image)
    else:
        image = im_path
    # print(np.array(image).shape)
    
    npix = image.shape[0]

    fourier_image = np.fft.fftn(image)
    fourier_amplitudes = np.abs(fourier_image)**2

    kfreq = np.fft.fftfreq(npix) * npix
    kfreq2D = np.meshgrid(kfreq, kfreq)
    knrm = np.sqrt(kfreq2D[0]**2 + kfreq2D[1]**2)

    knrm = knrm.flatten()
    fourier_amplitudes = fourier_amplitudes.flatten()

    kbins = np.arange(0.5, npix//2+1, 1.)
    kvals = 0.5 * (kbins[1:] + kbins[:-1])
    Abins, _, _ = stats.binned_statistic(knrm, fourier_amplitudes,
                                         statistic = "mean",
                                         bins = kbins)
    Abins *= np.pi * (kbins[1:]**2 - kbins[:-1]**2)
    if plot:
        plot_power_spectra([image],[kvals],[Abins])
    return kvals,Abins
```

And here is an example result:
[image: Sample ImageNet Image]

[image: Sample Output]

Comment: What is the purpose of `Abins *= np.pi * (kbins[1:]**2 - kbins[:-1]**2)`? Oh, I guess it's trying to normalize for the area over which the 2D FFT is averaged in the 1D plot. But because the `binned_statistic()` call uses the mean, this area is already taken care of. I don't think you need to normalize a second time!